# How to convert a json to json using external mapping

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, jackson-databind

We are calling an API in our java server which returns a json.
Now we want to convert this json into another json. But we want to have the conversion mapping in a separate file.
As an example,

```
Json A:
       {
         "json_id":"3",
         "json_another_id":"43",
         "code":34,
        "json_name":"Yey"
       }

To convert into Json B:

  {
     "id":"3",
     "another_id":"43",
     "code":34,
     "name":"Yeyproto"
  }
```

Below is the mapping which I want it to be present in the separate file:

```
"json_id" -> "id"
"json_another_id" -> "another_id"
"json_name" -> "name"
```

Please let me know a good solution for this. I have checked out jackson mixin but it converts from json to pojo

Comment: The optimal answer depends on how different you need the key names to be. If you're just removing "json" from all key names, you can simply use `java.lang.String` methods to find and replace the string you wish to be rid of. If you need more flexibility, however, I would recommend defining an enum with two fields (recieved key name and desired key name), iterating over a `JSONObject` or similar JSON-oriented construct, and replacing the entire recieved key name with the desired one.

Answer (score 0):

Try [JOLT](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt). It is a JSON to JSON transformation library written in Java where the "specification" for the transform is itself a JSON document. It was created on a project that was transforming lot of JSON from an ElasticSearch "backend" to a frontend api.

Answer (score 0):

One popular tool for JSON to JSON transforms in Java is [Jolt](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt). You can simply achieve this with given *Jolt Spec* as follows:

**Jolt Spec**

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@json_id": "id",
      "@json_another_id": "another_id",
      "@code": "code",
      "@json_name": "name"
    }
  }
]
```

You can verify it by [Jolt Transform Demo](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception) to put your original JSON string and the *Jolt Spec*, then press **Transform** button to see the result. Following code snippet shows how to achieve this in Java.

**Maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.jolt</groupId>
    <artifactId>jolt-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.jolt</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-utils</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Code snippet**

```
String spec = "[\r\n" +
        "  {\r\n" +
        "    \"operation\": \"shift\",\r\n" +
        "    \"spec\": {\r\n" +
        "      \"@json_id\": \"id\",\r\n" +
        "      \"@json_another_id\": \"another_id\",\r\n" +
        "      \"@code\": \"code\",\r\n" +
        "      \"@json_name\": \"name\"\r\n" +
        "    }\r\n" +
        "  }\r\n" +
        "]";
Chainr chainr = Chainr.fromSpec(JsonUtils.jsonToList(spec));
Object transformedOutput = chainr.transform(JsonUtils.jsonToObject(jsonStr));
System.out.println(transformedOutput.toString());
```

**Console output**

> {id=3, another_id=43, code=34, name=Yey}